# Is it possible to set durable permissions on an Azure storage blob or container?

Tags: azure, permissions, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I've been working with .NET for a while, but am only just now making the transition to Azure.

As part of my first cloud project I have a multi-user document scenario. Documents will be stored as BLOBs and each user needs to have access to their own documents, but nobody else's. In addition there are higher-level groups (Admins) with access to all docs. All users will be authenticated.

My question is: is there any way to attach a list of permitted users directly to a BLOB, or do I need to store this elsewhere (in Table Storage, or a DB)? I've found plenty of documentation on how to give temporary client access via a Shared Access signature, but nothing on more permanent 'file' permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to provide access control on your blob, the best option is to use ACS and DB. You can provide file access to specific users and save those access permissions into DB. This could be used as durable permission you requested.

You can take a look at BlobShare Sample is a simple file sharing application that demonstrates the storage services of the Windows Azure Platform, together with the authentication and authorization capabilities of Access Control Service (ACS).

http://blobshare.codeplex.com/

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to answer. That example is really useful.

Answer (score 1):

Blobs have no per-user access control built-in. The blob storage API service only has one security mechanism when working with private blobs: account key (primary or secondary keys both work the same). Shared Access Signatures are really just a way of providing temporary access via URL. If you do all of your user-level authorization in your web or business tier, that tier can direct-access a blob and return it directly to the user (via IIS, tomcat, web services, or whatever other mechanism you choose).

Since Windows Azure Storage has no ACS mechanism, you'll need to use a scheme similar to what you'd use with any other user-level access in your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the use of Shared access signature. for more details on shared access signature visit

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee395415.aspx
Regards,
Vijay.